# How can I solve this really easy number theory/modular arithmetic problem in Maple?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, maple

Math people:

This is more of a Maple question than a math question, but I think I will get an answer more quickly here than at mapleprimes.com.  I spent a lot of time on Google, mapleprimes.com, and in Maple's Help folders without finding an answer. Here is the question:

How do I solve $2x = 1 \mod 13$, working, of course, in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$, in Maple?  The correct answer is $7$, of course.  I tried

solve((2*x = 1) mod 13, x);

and I got

$\frac{1}{2}$

in return.  I apologize for asking such a simple question, but the Maple people did not make it easy to find an answer.

I am not interested in something such as pseudocode for the Euclidean algorithm, when there is probably a simple Maple command that gives the answer.

Stefan (STack Exchange FAN)

Comment: > msolve(2*x=1,13);

Comment: More details are here: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=msolve

Comment: @vadim123 : Thanks.  A question this easy hardly merits an actual answer, but if you turn your comment into an answer within a day or two, I'll accept it unless someone else posts an answer that is superior.

Comment: you're welcome.  Don't worry about the reputation, I'm just happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying comments by vadim123 so the question won't be bumped as unsolved:

`> msolve(2*x=1,13);`

[More details at Maplesoft site](http://maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=msolve)